# CKEditor dll for ASP.NET

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I am looking for CKEditor for ASP.NET but unable to use it because the dll library files are not provided in the setups available. Please guide how to include the dll library and provide any link where i can get those libraries.

Comment: The toll is available from http://ckeditor.com/download and I would be surprised if they did not provide a full product. Maybe you could describe the issues you're having in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET WebForms (not MVC) and you're willing to use an older version of CKEditor (3.x from 2014) then you can download CKEditor for ASP.NET from the [main download page](http://ckeditor.com/download). Scroll down until you see the "CKEditor 3.6.6.2 for ASP.NET" heading and click "Download now".

You'll get a zip file with a sample project including the DLL in debug and release versions. I just downloaded it now and it contains the DLLs.

Complete setup instructions are available [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Advanced).

However, if you're not using WebForms this will not be of any use to you. I would also strongly suggest using the latest version of CKEditor (4.5.9 at the time of writing) and just adding the CKEditor script to your pages along with a textbox to hold the editor content.